# Add a limit to the class selector "dog"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want this code to change the class of 3 divs **maximum** using jQuery.

```js
$(".cat, .dog").click(function() {
     var el = $(this);
     if(el.hasClass('cat')) {
         el.removeClass('cat');
         el.addClass('dog');

     } else {
         el.removeClass('dog');
         el.addClass('cat');
     }
});

// I tried with this code but it does not work, since I can keep dialing more than 3

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".cat").change(function () {
        var maxAllowed = 3;
        var cnt = $(".dog").length;
        if (cnt > maxAllowed) {
            addClass('cat');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.cat {
  background-color: #dadada;
}
.dog {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat">jQuery</div>
<br/>
<div class="cat">JavaScript</div>
<br/>
<div class="cat">Prototype</div>
<br/>
<div class="cat">Dojo</div>
<br/>
<div class="cat">Mootools</div>
<br/>
```

Comment: Your second code wouldnt work because div's don't fire a `change` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that, you have to add one more check: the amount of elements with class `dog` should be less than `maxAllowed` value. The condition should look something like that:

```
el.hasClass('cat') && activeDogs < maxAllowed // activeDogs - the amount of elements with class "dog"
```

And finally you will get something close to that:

```js
var maxAllowed = 3;
$(".cat, .dog").click(function() {
     var el = $(this);
     var activeDogs = $('.dog').length;
     if (el.hasClass('cat') && activeDogs < maxAllowed) {
         el.removeClass('cat');
         el.addClass('dog');
     } else {
         el.removeClass('dog');
         el.addClass('cat');
     }
});
```

```css
.cat {
  background-color: #dadada;
}

.dog {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cat">jQuery</div>
<br/>
<div class="cat">JavaScript</div>
<br/>
<div class="cat">Prototype</div>
<br/>
<div class="cat">Dojo</div>
<br/>
<div class="cat">Mootools</div>
<br/>
```

I get `$('.dog').length` every time, because I guess, that classes can be added/removed not only through this function. But if so, you can simply use a counter to achieve that and compare the counter with `maxAllowed` variable, this operation will take less resources.

```js
var maxAllowed = 3;
var activeDogs = 0;
$(".cat, .dog").click(function() {
     var el = $(this);
     if (el.hasClass('cat') && activeDogs < maxAllowed) {
         el.removeClass('cat');
         el.addClass('dog');
         activeDogs++;
     } else if (el.hasClass('dog')) {
         el.removeClass('dog');
         el.addClass('cat');
         activeDogs--;
     }
});
```

```css
.cat {
  background-color: #dadada;
}

.dog {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cat">jQuery</div>
<br/>
<div class="cat">JavaScript</div>
<br/>
<div class="cat">Prototype</div>
<br/>
<div class="cat">Dojo</div>
<br/>
<div class="cat">Mootools</div>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to increment the count after you add the `cat` class:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var count = 0;
  $(".cat").change(function () {
    if (count < 3) {
        addClass('cat');
        count++;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if you have less than 3 "dogs" (red colored rows) before allowing the class change:

```js
$(".cat, .dog").click(function() {
     var el = $(this);
     if(el.hasClass('cat') && $('.dog').length < 3) {
         el.removeClass('cat');
         el.addClass('dog');

     } else {
         el.removeClass('dog');
         el.addClass('cat');
     }
});

// I tried with this code but it does not work, since I can keep dialing more than 3
```

```css
.cat {
background-color: #dadada;
}
.dog {
background-color: red;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat">jQuery</div>
<br/>
<div class="cat">JavaScript</div>
<br/>
<div class="cat">Prototype</div>
<br/>
<div class="cat">Dojo</div>
<br/>
<div class="cat">Mootools</div>
<br/>
```